# Converting one to many to one to one table in SQL

Tags: sql, one-to-one

I need some SQL guidance.
I have a table (A) that looks like this (note the rows *should* be unique by ID+CommType):

| Member ID | CommType | Consent | Emailable |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | News | Yes | Yes |
| 2 | News | Yes | No |
| 1 | Surveys | No |  |
| 2 | Surveys | Yes | Yes |
| 1 | Events | Yes |  |
| 3 | News | No | No |

Which I want to end up as follows (unique row by Member ID).

For added complexity, the rules for the final table values for each CommType:

```
(Yes if both Consent and Emailable = Yes for CommType)
(No if Emailable = No for CommType)
(NULL if Emailable = null or no row for CommType)
```

| Member ID | News | Surveys | Events |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | Yes |  |  |
| 2 | No | Yes |  |
| 3 | No |  |  |

Comment: this relates to using SQL in Salesforce Marketing Cloud (SFMC) per this article if that helps: https://mateuszdabrowski.pl/docs/sql/sfmc-sql-select/

Answer (score 0):

You can try the following - note this assumes you have a reasonable number of different CommTypes and you know all the possible values:

```sql
SELECT member_id
, MIN(CASE WHEN CommType='News' THEN CASE WHEN Consent = 'Yes' AND Emailable='Yes' THEN 'Yes' WHEN Emailable = 'No' THEN 'No' END END) AS news
, MIN(CASE WHEN CommType='Surveys' THEN CASE WHEN Consent = 'Yes' AND Emailable='Yes' THEN 'Yes' WHEN Emailable = 'No' THEN 'No' END END) AS surveys
, MIN(CASE WHEN CommType='Events' THEN CASE WHEN Consent = 'Yes' AND Emailable='Yes' THEN 'Yes' WHEN Emailable = 'No' THEN 'No' END END) AS events
-- , ..., do the same for each possible CommType
FROM your_table
GROUP BY member_id
```